# Why does auto-generated iOS Apple code use instance variables instead of properties?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I did a lot of iOS development pre-ARC. Now with ARC I've noticed that Apple generated code is using instance variables instead of properties. Why is that?

For instance a master-detail view controller - on the DetailView we see this:

```
- (void)setDetailItem:(id)newDetailItem
{
if (_detailItem != newDetailItem) {
    _detailItem = newDetailItem;

    // Update the view.
    [self configureView];
}
}
```

Why not self.detailItem = newDetailItem;?  When I first learned iOS dev the use of properties was the recommended practice.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`self.detailItem = newDetailItem;` IS `[self setDetailItem:newDetailItem];`

So that would cause a stack overflow.

When you declare a property it already defines the getter and the setter for an instance variable (unless it's in a category). So if you have to customize either the getter or the setter then you need to access the instance variable directly.

Comment: Hey Moxy - I didn't realize it was the setter method :P Bad example - I have seen @synthesize myIVAR = _myIVar - that is really the question I am asking

Comment: It's not necessary to call @synthesize as of iOS 6. When you declare the property, the iVar and synthesize methods are automatically created. It was in one of the WWDC videos from WWDC2012.

Comment: With modern objective c, you still need to use `@synthesize` when you manually define both the getter and the setter.

Comment: True. I tend not to have to manually declare @synthesize (very very rarely), so I forgot that I have to do that. Thanks for the correction.

Answer (score 8):

It would create a infinitive recursive loop. Since self.detailItem = obj; calls:

```
- (void)setDetailItem:(id)newDetailItem
```

Regarding the "_" it's how the variable is named when you don't syntersize it. You can change it if you want, although i see no reason to do that.